# Unable to get details from hash fetch fragment after Auth redirection in Angular 4

Tags: angular, redirect, access-token

After authorisation browser is getting redirected to the url

http://127.0.0.1:4200/#/homepage&access_token=&token_type=bearer&state=XYZ&expires_in=3599

But before I fetch the details everything is getting scrapped off and the browser url address shown is http://127.0.0.1:4200/#/homepage

I have tried couple of things in Home page component like

```
this.route.fragment.subscribe((fragment: string) => {
        console.log("My hash fragment is here => ", fragment)
    })
```

But I am getting fragment as null.

```
router.events.subscribe(s => {
            if (s instanceof NavigationCancel) {
                let params = new URLSearchParams(s.url.split('#')[1]);
                this.access_token = params.get('access_token');
                let code = params.get('code');

                console.log("Access_Token: "+this.access_token);

            }
        });
```

Here the code is never reached.

Comment: add more tags to reach more people.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following code:

```
constructor(router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe(s => {
      console.log(s);
      if (s instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        const fragments = router.parseUrl(router.url);
        // do your logic
      }
    });
}
```

In case, you're using **hashlocationstrategy**, you can try to do the following:

```
constructor(router: Router) {
    router.events
      .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
      .filter(event => (/access_token|id_token|error/).test(event.url))
      .subscribe(s => {
         console.log(window.location.hash);
         // you will do some works on window.location.hash
    });
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried this but the fragments part is just shown as /homepage instead of the entire url. I think that is because the browser is redirecting the page and those are not recorded in the router events

Comment: Are you using HashLocationStrategy for your routing?

Comment: Yes I'm using HashLocationStrategy as I'm using nginx to deploy I'm getting 404 when using PathLocationStrategy

Comment: Using the above for HashLocationStrategy is not working. As the hash is removed even before component is initialized. The update is working properly when I am using PathLocationStrategy and I am able to fetch the hash fragment but I am back to square one as Ngnix starts throwing 404 thinking /homepage as new page I guess. Any work around to use Nginx+Angular+PathLocationStrategy?